# show a UIButton when the UITableView is in editing mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to show a UIButton when the UITableView is in editing mode like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSLog(@"deleting :%i", indexPath.row);

        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        self.buttonAdd.hidden = FALSE;

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
[self.table reloadData];
}
```

But this doesn't work, do you have any ideas?

Comment: [tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];

Comment: what about know still have problem ?

Comment: yes I'm trying use setEditing method below ;)

Comment: If it is still not working that mean there is something else ???

Comment: i think so, what i want is to set a uibutton when editing the table which is in viewcontroller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19568/discussion-between-omarj-and-tchike)

Comment: did you make [UIButton alloc] initWithFram:CGRectMake(0,0,20,40)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Make sure you call super first
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing)
    {
         do your code
      //  self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel");
    }
    else
    {
              do your code
       // self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
    }
}
```