# How to change Edit/Done button title in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If Editing mode is enabled for the tableview it shows a button titled Edit, when pressing it it changes the title to done

i was wondering if there is a way to change the Done Button title to something else ?

i already changed the title for the done button.

the code i used is

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.editButtonItem.title = @"Change";
```

Now The Edit is Change

How to make Done to something else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the title of the edit button like this:-

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Make sure you call super first
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing)
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
    }
}
```

its working like edit:-

[image]

TO

[image]

Comment: i did, but it was telling me to wait for some time :)

Comment: @NitinGohel: copied answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386715/show-a-uibutton-when-the-uitableview-is-in-editing-mode. Please put atleast the copied link

Comment: One morep oint: if you want to change Edit button title (and show custom title on controller start you need to add this to your viewDidLoad: self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Custom edit", @"Custom edit button text - Edit state");

Answer (score 8):

Here is the method to change it for Swift

```
override func setEditing (editing:Bool, animated:Bool)
{
    super.setEditing(editing,animated:animated)
    if (self.editing) {
        self.editButtonItem().title = "Editing"
    }
    else {
        self.editButtonItem().title = "Not Editing"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Nitin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429811/2547229) I suggest a slightly different approach that uses the built in `UIButtonBar` system items.

This will give your UI the system look & feel. For example, the standard "Done" button to cease editing should have a specific **bold** look on iOS 8. Apple might change these stylings in future. By using the system defined buttons your app will pick up the current aesthetic automatically.

This approach also provides you with free string localisation. Apple have already translated the system button titles for you in to the dozens of languages that iOS supports.

Here's the code I've got:

```
-(IBAction) toggleEditing:(id)sender
{
  [self setEditing: !self.editing animated: YES];
}

-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];

  const UIBarButtonSystemItem systemItem = 
    editing ? 
    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone : 
    UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;

  UIBarButtonItem *const newButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem: systemItem 
                           target: self 
                           action: @selector(toggleEditing:)];

  [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems: @[newButton] animated: YES];
}
```

The example here is for the case where your `UIViewController` is hosted in a `UINavigationController` and so has a `UINavigationItem` instance. If you're not doing this, you'll need to update the bar item in an appropriate way.

In your `viewDidLoad` use the following call to configure the edit button ready for use:

```
[self setEditing: NO animated: NO];
```

Comment: Nice time saving solution, no need in localized strings.