# How to change text of edit and done button in obcjective-c?

Tags: ios, button, text, edit, title

I want to change the text of the "Edit" and "Done" button which is on the navigation bar, on my iOS app written in objective-c, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you really made any attempt to write code or have you tried to search on a search engine called @"Google". There are more than 20 question  answered on stack-overflow on this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the title of the "back" button on a Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar)

Comment: On tap of barButton, you could change the text self.editButon using setText method. Also don't forget to connect a IBOutlet of your barButton.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Edit/Done button title in UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429743/how-to-change-edit-done-button-title-in-uinavigationbar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429743/how-to-change-edit-done-button-title-in-uinavigationbar ]

Answer (score 0):

This is want you want.

```
    UIButton *btncustome = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
    [btncustome setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btncustome setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btncustome] ;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbtn;
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the UIBarButton from the `UINavigationController` and use `setTitle` method to change the text.

```
UINavigationItem *items = [[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] items] lastObject];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [item leftBarButtonItem];
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [item rightBarButtonItem];

    [cancelButton setTitle:@"New Title"];
    [editButton setTitle:@"New Title"];
```